# UnknownHostException for Eureka Client using RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, service-discovery

I have a simple setup with a Eureka Server and two microservices that serves as Eureka Clients. One microservice should be able to make calls to the other. On the webinterface of the Eureka server I can see that the service is registered with the name "my-service" which I have set in application.properties.

I've read several Questions on that on stackoveflow. The answer almost always is to add the annotation @LoadBalanced to the Autowired RestTemplate. Unfortunately, I've done this and I still get the UnknownHostException.

[Microservices - RestTemplate UnknownHostException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37159662/microservices-resttemplate-unknownhostexception)

[spring-boot Autowired DiscoveryClient RestTemplate UnknownHostException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36458975/spring-boot-autowired-discoveryclient-resttemplate-unknownhostexception)

My Bean in the Config:

```
@LoadBalanced
@Bean
RestTemplate restTemplate() {
    return new RestTemplate();
}
```

My Microservice calling the my-service:

```
public class MyCallingService {

    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    public JsonArray makeCall() {
    ResponseEntity<JsonArray> response = this.restTemplate
                .getForObject("http://my-service/api/call", JsonArray.class);
        return response.getBody();
    }
}
```

When I make a call from the the one microservice to the other, I get an UnknownHostException for my-service.

EDIT: I missed some information from which I thought that it doesn't cause this behavior but it turns out it does: I'm calling makeCall() within another beans method that is annotated with @PostConstruct. If I call makeCall() after the dependency injection, I don't get the UnknownHostException and I can make the call. Can someone argue why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using spring boot and spr,then use this

```
  @Bean
  @LoadBalanced
  public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {
    return builder.build();
  }
```